# how to setting mongoose schema createAt timezone dayjs

Tags: mongodb, express, dayjs

The area I live in is UTC +9.

`default: Date.now() + 9 * 60 * 60 * 1000`

I can do it like this, but I want to use dayjs. I tried the code below, but it didn't work Is there a way?

```js
import { Schema, model, Types } from 'mongoose';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';

dayjs.extend(timezone);
dayjs.extend(utc);

dayjs().tz('Asia/Seoul');

const commentSchema = new Schema({
  commenter: {
    type: Types.ObjectId,
    require: true,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: dayjs().tz('Asia/Seoul').format(),
  },
});

const comment = model('Commenet', commentSchema);

export default comment;
```

Comment: Running `Date.now() + 9 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is wrong. By this you don't set the time zone, you change the actual time value. UTC time is always the same, no matter if you are in Asia or not. `Date` objects in MongoDB are UTC - **always and only**! Usually the client application is responsible to **display** the time as local time. If you need to preserve the input time zone, then you need to store the time zone in a separate field.

Comment: When the data type is `Date`, then you should use `toDate()` instead of `format()` which returns a string.